# Index Was Out Of Range. Must Be Non Negative And Less Then The Size Of Collection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two list (girlsLIST1  and girlsLIST2 ) of strings in which i have 5 string values but when i increase those values to 6 i get an exception here is my code. now i have questions variable on the basis of the value of questions variable the for loops run and pick some random strings from list and store those results in girl1names  and girl2names list. Currently the value of my question variable is 5 but if i increase the strings in my girlsLIST1 and girlsLIST2 list like more than 5 then i get an exception.

```
List<string> girlsLIST1 = new List<string> { "Aliya", "Manal", "Ayman", "Laiba", "Lubna", "Aziza" };
List<string> girlsLIST2 = new List<string> { "Mehmoona", "Samra", "Saria", "Aleena", "Faiza","Mehwish" };
List<string> girl1names = new List<string>();
List<string> girl2names = new List<string>();
int GirlName;
int GirlName2;
if (addquestions == true)
{
    //for (int i = 0; i <girlsLIST1.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    int Girlsnames1 = random.Next(girlsLIST1.Count);
    //    GirlName = girlsLIST1[Girlsnames1];
    //}
    //for (int i = 0; i < girlsLIST2.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    int Girlsnames2 = random.Next(girlsLIST2.Count);
    //    GirlName2 = girlsLIST2[Girlsnames2];
    //}
    var random = new Random();
    int min = 2;
    int max = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++)
    {
        GirlName = random.Next(girlsLIST1.Count);
        GirlName2 = random.Next(girlsLIST2.Count);
        girl1names.Add(girlsLIST1[GirlName]);
        girl2names.Add(girlsLIST2[GirlName2]);
    }

    var list = new List<string>
    {
        girl1names[GirlName] +" was playing basketball. " + random.Next(min, max) + " of her shots went in the hoop. " + random.Next(min, max) + " of her shots did not go in the hoop. How many shots were there in total?",
        "The restaurant has " + random.Next(min, max) + " normal chairs and " + random.Next(min, max) +" chairs for babies. How many chairs does the restaurant have in total?",
        "How many cookies did you sell if you sold " + random.Next(min, max) + " chocolate cookies and " + random.Next(min, max) + " vanilla cookies?",
        girl2names[GirlName2] + " bought a big bag of candy. The bag had " + random.Next(min, max) + " blue candies, " + random.Next(min, max) + " red candies and " + random.Next(min, max) + " green candies. How many candies were there in total?",
        girl1names[GirlName] + " had " + random.Next(min, max) + " books at home. He went to the library to take out " + random.Next(min, max) + " more books. He then bought 1 book. How many books does Billy have now?",
        "The hobby store normally sells " + random.Next(min, max) + " trading cards per month. In June, the hobby store sold " + random.Next(min, max) + " more trading cards than normal. In total, how many trading cards did the hobby store sell in June?",
        girl2names[GirlName2] + " has " + random.Next(min, max) + " pieces of gum to share with her friends. There wasn’t enough gum for all her friends, so she went to the store to get " + random.Next(min, max) + " more pieces of gum. How many pieces of gum does Adrianna have now?",
        girl1names[GirlName] + " has " + random.Next(min, max) + " pieces of gum to share with her friends. There wasn’t enough gum for all her friends, so she went to the store and got " + random.Next(min, max) + " pieces of strawberry gum and " + random.Next(min, max) + " pieces of bubble gum. How many pieces of gum does Adrianna have now?"
    };
    genericfunction(list);
    //int index = randoms.Next(list.Count);

    //DisplayAlert("word problems", list[index], "ok");

    //Creates a new Word document 
    WordDocument wordDocument = new WordDocument();

    //Adds new section with single paragraph to the document
    wordDocument.EnsureMinimal();
    wordDocument.LastSection.PageSetup.Margins.All = 15;
    //Get Last paragraph of the document
    IWParagraph paragraph = wordDocument.LastParagraph;
    //Create a custom style
    WParagraphStyle paragraphStyle = wordDocument.Styles.FindByName("Normal") as WParagraphStyle;
    paragraphStyle.CharacterFormat.Font = new Syncfusion.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 20);
    paragraphStyle.ParagraphFormat.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Justify;
    paragraphStyle.ParagraphFormat.AfterSpacing = 15f;
    WSection section = wordDocument.LastSection;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordproblemslist.Count; i++)
    {
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        string t = wordproblemslist[i];
        paragraph.AppendText(t);
    }

    //Adds new text to the paragraph
    //paragraph.AppendText(text);
    //Adds first text to the paragraph
    //  paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
    // paragraph.AppendText(text);
    //Second paragraph
    //  paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
    //  paragraph.AppendText(text);
    //Instantiation of DocIORenderer for Word to PDF conversion
    DocIORenderer render = new DocIORenderer();
    //Converts Word document into PDF document
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = render.ConvertToPDF(wordDocument);
    //Releases all resources used by the Word document and DocIO Renderer objects
    render.Dispose();
    wordDocument.Dispose();
    //Save the document into memory stream
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfDocument.Save(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    //Close the document 
    pdfDocument.Close();
    //Save the stream into pdf file
    //The operation in Save under Xamarin varies between Windows Phone, Android and iOS platforms. Please refer PDF/Xamarin section for respective code samples.

    Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISave>().SaveAndView("Output.pdf", "application/pdf", stream);

    wordproblemslist.Clear();
    girl1names.Clear();
    girl2names.Clear();
    private void genericfunction( List<string> list)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        List<int> listNumbers = new List<int>();

        int number;
        for (int j = 0; j < questions; j++)
        {
            do
            {
                number = randoms.Next(list.Count);
            } while (listNumbers.Contains(number));
            listNumbers.Add(number);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < listNumbers.Count; k++)
        {
            wordproblemslist.Add(list[listNumbers[k]]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Did you try which part of the code throwing the error? 2) Instead of pasting all the code, you could break the code into chunks and try explaining what each part of the code does.

Comment: `girl1names[GirlName]` this feels wrong, because `GirlName` is a number between 0 and `girlsLIST1.Count`, which could very well be way more than `girl1names.Count`

Comment: the list part in which i have added the long string questions

Comment: @Rafalon i didnt understand what you said please can you explain more

Comment: Did you check my solution and solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `GirlName` this way:

```
GirlName = random.Next(girlsLIST1.Count);
```

So here, `GirlName` will be something between `0` and `5`.

**THEN**, you are *trying* to get a name from `girl1names` this way:

```
girl1names[GirlName]
```

**BUT**, `girl1names` only contains `questions` names, because you filled this list this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++)
{
    girl1names.Add(girlsLIST1[GirlName]);
}
```

**THEREFORE**, if it happens that `GirlName` is greater or equal to `questions`, you're out.

(Same goes for `girl2names[GirlName2]`)

---

### Solution

Don't try to access `girl1names[GirlName]`.

Use an index that won't go over `girl1names`'s length (and maybe re-think of what index you **really** want to reach, because `GirlName` is ***very unlikely*** to be the one you're looking for)

Same for `girl2names`.

Comment: ok so how can i solve this problem can u write a right code for me

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

You get exception that says `Index Was Out Of Range. Must Be Non Negative And Less Then The Size Of Collection` means that the index of object you want to get is out of Range.

It happens here: `girl1names[GirlName]` and `girl2names[GirlName2]`.

`girl1names`: It's a list the hold the names. Its count is depending on the `value` of **questions**.

`GirlName`: work as `Index` here. Its max value is depending on **girlsLIST1.Count**.

To prevent the exception you get, you should make sure the value of `GirlName` is less than length of `girl1names`.

So, this means, the value of **girlsLIST1.Count** you defined should less than **questions**.(the same as `girl2names[GirlName2]`)

I guess your value of question is less than 4, so if you increase  5 string values to 6, it will crash.

**Solution:**

Make sure the value of **questions** bigger than both **girlsLIST1.Count** and **girlsLIST2.Count**.